# Edit content data are not reflected in DNN content staging

Tags: dotnetnuke

Edit content data are not reflected in DNN content staging. We setup content staging in DNN(we are using Enterprise edition 6.2.8), if we change the module settings it gets reflected in Content Staging update, if we update Edit content(we have seprate edit/view settings) same module, its not reflected in content staging update.

Answer (score 1):

Content Staging in DNN flat out doesn't work and shouldn't be sold as a feature.

(Former DNN Trainer who hated having customers want training on that feature)

Comment: Is there any official link is there , related to content staging flat out.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but you also won't likely find it listed on the website anywhere either (cept on very old WIKI pages) http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Solutions/Evoq-Content